# Swift 3.0 How to dismiss keyboard on a Search Bar when clicking outside of the bar

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

As stated in the title, I am interested in dismissing the keyboard from a search bar when clicking outside of the search bar. Similar questions stated to used self.view.endEditing(true) in touchesBegan, but I have had no luck. I am not sure if I am missing anything else, or if I have set up my searchBar correctly.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class AddressVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()




    @IBOutlet weak var searchResultsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        searchResultsTableView.isHidden = true

        searchCompleter.delegate = self
    }




extension AddressVC: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchText
}

func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    searchResultsTableView.isHidden = false
    return true

}

func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchResultsTableView.isHidden = true
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}


}
```

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/49833833/1084174 may help

Answer (score 6):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddressVC.dismissKeyboard))

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Above solution didn't work for a searchBar in a navigationController. I changed view.endEditing(true) to self.searchBar.endEditing(true) and that worked.