# On hiding keyboard after edit , UISearchbar hides itself?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, first-responder, resignfirstresponder

I have presented a screen using navigation controller and in that screen I have a search bar , which I have made as first responder in viewWillAppear() . The problem is that I want to hide keyboard when done button is clicked or cancel in searchBar is clicked. But on doing the same with both resignFirstResponder() and searchBar.endEditing(true) , it also hides UISearchBar. I want to show UISearchBar when the state is not in edit also .

Basically what I have done is I have made my UISearchBar my first responder as such :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

then when user clicks search I have made :

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    // Remove focus from the search bar.
}
```

Same is the case with cancel button . But in my case instead of just dismissing the keyboard , this also hides UISearchbar() after calling the above function.

Comment: provide some more detail and code where you are doing this.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan added.

Answer (score 0):

Use NotificationCenter addObserver to get an event of keyboard show and keyboard Hide

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHideNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

// MARK: - Keyboard Hide/Show Functions
@objc func keyboardWillShowNotification(notification: Notification) {
    print("Keyboaed Show")
}

@objc func keyboardWillHideNotification(notification: Notification) {
    print("Keyboaed Hide")
}
```

**Note:-** Don't forget to remove the observer when `UIviewContoller` will disappear.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: my problem is not with keyboard hiding , its with uisearchbar hiding with it.

Comment: have you checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925373/how-to-make-keyboard-dismiss-when-i-press-out-of-searchbar-on-swift

Comment: have you assigned the delegate to UIsearchbar? It may be causing an issue